# Changing My working script to Dockable script does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I have a working script for after effects, but when I change it to Dockable script,it wont work. Please help me to figure out why? If I take it out of the dock script it is working. I copied this dockable code from goodboy.ninja website.

This the final Dockable Code. Where is the mistake?

```js
(
  function(thisObj) {

    buildUI(thisObj);

    ‍

    function buildUI(thisObj) {

      var windowName = "Diffrence Checker";

      var myPanel = (thisObj instanceof Panel) ? thisObj : new Window("window", windowName, undefined, {
        resizeable: true
      });

      // Dropdown list

      var groupOne = myPanel.add("group", undefined, "groupOne");
      groupOne.orientation = "row";
      groupOne.add("StaticText", undefined, "Main Comp");
      var mainDD = groupOne.add("dropdownlist", undefined, compArrayNames);
      mainDD.size = [175, 25];

      var groupTwo = myPanel.add("group", undefined, "groupTwo");
      groupTwo.orientation = "row";
      groupTwo.add("StaticText", undefined, "Diff File");
      var diffDD = groupTwo.add("dropdownlist", undefined, VideoArrayNames);
      diffDD.size = [175, 25];

      // Button code

      var createBT = myPanel.add("group", undefined, "createBT");
      createBT.orientation = "column";
      var mainbutton = createBT.add("button", undefined, "Create");


      //myPanel.center();
      //myPanel.show();
      ‍
      myPanel.onResizing = myPanel.onResize = function() {
        this.layout.resize();
      };
      if (myPanel instanceof Window) {
        myPanel.center();
        myPanel.show();
      } else {
        myPanel.layout.layout(true);
        myPanel.layout.resize();
      }

    }

    // Write your helper functions here
    var compArray = [];
    var compArrayNames = [];
    var VideoArray = [];
    var VideoArrayNames = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= app.project.numItems; i++) {
      if (app.project.item(i).hasVideo == true && app.project.item(i).file == null) {
        compArray.push(app.project.item(i));
        compArrayNames.push(app.project.item(i).name);
      }
      if (app.project.item(i).hasVideo == true && app.project.item(i).hasAudio == true) {
        VideoArray.push(app.project.item(i));
        VideoArrayNames.push(app.project.item(i).name);
      }
    }

    function createCP() {
      app.beginUndoGroup("Editing");
      var comlayer = compArray[mainDD.selection.index];
      var vidlayer = VideoArray[diffDD.selection.index];
      var getcomp = app.project.items.addComp(VideoArrayNames[diffDD.selection.index] + "_DIFF".toString(), 1920, 1080, 1, comlayer.duration, 30);
      getcomp.openInViewer();
      addVideofile(comlayer, getcomp);
      addvideotwofile(vidlayer);
      renderQ();
      app.endUndoGroup();
    }

    function addVideofile(comlayer) {
      app.project.activeItem.layers.add(comlayer);



    }

    function addvideotwofile(vidlayer) {
      var newlayer = app.project.activeItem.layers.add(vidlayer);
      newlayer.blendingMode = BlendingMode.DIFFERENCE;

    }

    function renderQ() {

      var Qcomp = app.project.activeItem;
      var Qitem = app.project.renderQueue.items.add(Qcomp);
    }
  }
)
(this);
```

My Original script is as follows:

```
// Diffrence Check
// global variables
var compArray = [];
var compArrayNames = [];
var VideoArray = [];
var VideoArrayNames = [];


for (var i = 1; i <= app.project.numItems; i++){
    if (app.project.item(i).hasVideo == true && app.project.item(i).file == null) {
        compArray.push (app.project.item(i));
        compArrayNames.push (app.project.item(i).name);
        }
    if (app.project.item(i).hasVideo == true && app.project.item(i).hasAudio== true) {
        VideoArray.push (app.project.item(i));
        VideoArrayNames.push (app.project.item(i).name);
        }
    }


var mainWindow = new Window("palette","Difference Checker",undefined);
mainWindow.orientation= "column";

// Dropdown list

var groupOne = mainWindow.add("group",undefined,"groupOne");
groupOne.orientation = "row";
groupOne.add("StaticText",undefined,"Main Comp");
var mainDD = groupOne.add("dropdownlist",undefined,compArrayNames);
mainDD.size = [175,25];

var groupTwo = mainWindow.add("group",undefined,"groupTwo");
groupTwo.orientation = "row";
groupTwo.add("StaticText",undefined,"Diff File");
var diffDD = groupTwo.add("dropdownlist",undefined,VideoArrayNames);
diffDD.size = [175,25];

// Button code

var createBT = mainWindow.add("group",undefined,"createBT");
createBT.orientation = "column";
var mainbutton = createBT.add("button",undefined,"Create");


mainWindow.center();
mainWindow.show();


// Main Code Begins

mainbutton.onClick = function(){
    createCP();
    }

// Main Function Code

function createCP() {
       app.beginUndoGroup("Editing");
        var comlayer = compArray[mainDD.selection.index];
        var vidlayer = VideoArray[diffDD.selection.index];
        var getcomp = app.project.items.addComp(VideoArrayNames[diffDD.selection.index]+"_DIFF".toString(),1920,1080,1,comlayer.duration,30);
        getcomp.openInViewer();
        addVideofile(comlayer,getcomp);
        addvideotwofile(vidlayer);
        renderQ();
        app.endUndoGroup();
    }

function addVideofile(comlayer) {
    app.project.activeItem.layers.add(comlayer);
    
     
    
    }
function addvideotwofile(vidlayer){
   var newlayer = app.project.activeItem.layers.add(vidlayer);
     newlayer.blendingMode = BlendingMode.DIFFERENCE;
    
     
    // var outputModule = item.outputModule()
    }
function renderQ(){
    
     var Qcomp =app.project.activeItem;
     var Qitem = app.project.renderQueue.items.add(Qcomp);
     }
```

Comment: You have an invisible space character between `buildUI(thisObj);

    ‍

    function buildUI(thisObj) {`

Comment: and again after  `//myPanel.show();
      ‍`

Comment: i used extendscript to write my script..but the dock script is copied from online.

Answer (score 1):

You have an invisible Zero-Width Joiner between

```
buildUI(thisObj);      ‍
```

and

```
function buildUI(thisObj) {
```

and again after

```
//myPanel.show();
```

```js
const toHex = str => {
    var result = '';
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
      result += str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return result;
  };

const stringWithJoiner = ` ‍`; // space (20) and joiner (200D)

console.log(toHex(stringWithJoiner))
```

Here is your script without it

```js
(function(thisObj) {
  buildUI(thisObj);

  function buildUI(thisObj) {

    var windowName = "Diffrence Checker";

    var myPanel = (thisObj instanceof Panel) ? thisObj : new Window("window", windowName, undefined, {
      resizeable: true
    });

    // Dropdown list

    var groupOne = myPanel.add("group", undefined, "groupOne");
    groupOne.orientation = "row";
    groupOne.add("StaticText", undefined, "Main Comp");
    var mainDD = groupOne.add("dropdownlist", undefined, compArrayNames);
    mainDD.size = [175, 25];

    var groupTwo = myPanel.add("group", undefined, "groupTwo");
    groupTwo.orientation = "row";
    groupTwo.add("StaticText", undefined, "Diff File");
    var diffDD = groupTwo.add("dropdownlist", undefined, VideoArrayNames);
    diffDD.size = [175, 25];

    // Button code

    var createBT = myPanel.add("group", undefined, "createBT");
    createBT.orientation = "column";
    var mainbutton = createBT.add("button", undefined, "Create");
    //myPanel.center();
    //myPanel.show();
    myPanel.onResizing = myPanel.onResize = function() {
      this.layout.resize();
    };
    if (myPanel instanceof Window) {
      myPanel.center();
      myPanel.show();
    } else {
      myPanel.layout.layout(true);
      myPanel.layout.resize();
    }

  }

  // Write your helper functions here
  var compArray = [];
  var compArrayNames = [];
  var VideoArray = [];
  var VideoArrayNames = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= app.project.numItems; i++) {
    if (app.project.item(i).hasVideo == true && app.project.item(i).file == null) {
      compArray.push(app.project.item(i));
      compArrayNames.push(app.project.item(i).name);
    }
    if (app.project.item(i).hasVideo == true && app.project.item(i).hasAudio == true) {
      VideoArray.push(app.project.item(i));
      VideoArrayNames.push(app.project.item(i).name);
    }
  }

  function createCP() {
    app.beginUndoGroup("Editing");
    var comlayer = compArray[mainDD.selection.index];
    var vidlayer = VideoArray[diffDD.selection.index];
    var getcomp = app.project.items.addComp(VideoArrayNames[diffDD.selection.index] + "_DIFF".toString(), 1920, 1080, 1, comlayer.duration, 30);
    getcomp.openInViewer();
    addVideofile(comlayer, getcomp);
    addvideotwofile(vidlayer);
    renderQ();
    app.endUndoGroup();
  }

  function addVideofile(comlayer) {
    app.project.activeItem.layers.add(comlayer);
  }

  function addvideotwofile(vidlayer) {
    var newlayer = app.project.activeItem.layers.add(vidlayer);
    newlayer.blendingMode = BlendingMode.DIFFERENCE;

  }

  function renderQ() {

    var Qcomp = app.project.activeItem;
    var Qitem = app.project.renderQueue.items.add(Qcomp);
  }
})
(this);
```